# Alternate data result SPFX

Tags: jquery, spfx, spfx-webparts, ajax

Hi all I'm trying to build an spfx webpart for project server 2019 (on prem)... Everything it was working good, I used this css but now I faced an interesting question, css have two elements container left and container right. How can I alternate in elements?

my webpart.ts:

```
$.ajax({
  url: `${this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl}`+
  `/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Entregas')/items?$select=Title,CommitmentFinish,Description`,
  method: 'GET',
  async: false,
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json; odata=verbose'
  },
  success: (data) => {
    let html = `<div class="row"><div class="col-md-12">sem eventos registrados</div></div>`;

    if (data.d.results.length > 0) {
      html = "";
      $.each(data.d.results, (i, result) => {

        html += `<div>`+
                `<div class="timeline">`+
                `<div class="container left">`+
                `<i class="icon"></i>`+
                `<div class="content"><h2>${result.Title}</h2><p>${result.Description}</p></div>`+                    
                `<div class="date">${new Date(result.CommitmentFinish).toLocaleDateString('pt-br', option)}</div>`+
                `</div>`;
                
      });

      $("#divDeliver").html(html);
    }
    else
    {
      $("#divDeliver").html(html);
    }

  },
  error: (errorCode, errorMessage) => {
    console.log('Erro ao recuperar os itens. \nError: ' + errorCode + '\nStackTrace: ' + errorMessage);
  }
});
```

The result is:
[image]

The second object must be align in right.

How can I alternate between left and right results?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using [jQuery's each](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/), you are given the index of the item as the first parameter of the callback. You can use that to alternate the class you assign. Try changing that portion of the code to the following:

```
      $.each(data.d.results, (i, result) => {

        html += `<div>`+
                `<div class="timeline">`+
                `<div class="container ${(i%2==1 ? 'left' : 'right')}">`+
                `<i class="icon"></i>`+
                `<div class="content"><h2>${result.Title}</h2><p>${result.Description}</p></div>`+                    
                `<div class="date">${new Date(result.CommitmentFinish).toLocaleDateString('pt-br', option)}</div>`+
                `</div>`;
                
      });
```

Comment: Hi! thanks for reply! I changed the portion of code but is returned a error: [14:57:58] Error - typescript - src\webparts\timeLineWebpart\TimeLineWebpartWebPart.ts(49,46): error TS2362: The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number' or an enum type.